# C++ - Compiling error on a tree homework : error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I'm currently trying to do a homework, and I'm trying to get my things to compile at first (class headers in the .h file, and the empty definitions in the .inl file (I'm using the typename template)).

I'm getting this error :

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
```

Here's my .h file : http://ideone.com/dm3Bp

Here's my .inl file: http://ideone.com/5FBep

I'm trying to make a Node (called Noeud, in these files) at the end of the .inl file.
apparently, I can't take a value from array of type E data...

The error is just before the definition of the method:

```
Noeud * Arbre<E>::_auxPereSym(E *tabS, int debut, int fin, E **ptr, int &card) throw (std::bad_alloc)
```

I've read in other threads that the return type should be Arbre< E >::Noeud Because Noeud is a nested structure of my class Arbre... But unfortunately, I can't change the header file...

Any thoughts?

Thanks for you time and help.

Note: Let me know if a translation is needed for anything, this is a french homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to qualify as so while defining in .inl file (and not the header file as per your concern).

The return type needs to be looked up in the proper scope appropriately.

BRAIN COMPILED CODE AHEAD

```
template<typename E>
typename Arbre<E>::Noeud * Arbre<E>::_auxPereSym(E *tabS, int debut, int fin, E **ptr, int &card) throw (std::bad_alloc)
```

EDIT2:

change return statement in the member function as so:

```
return new typename Arbre<E>::Noeud(tabS[0]);
```

Comment: I tried doing that, and now I have another error, that might not be related, but it says : ../BST.h: In constructor ‘Arbre_Lab8::Arbre<E>::Noeud::Noeud(const E&) [with E = int]’:
../BST.inl:78:   instantiated from ‘Arbre_Lab8::Arbre<E>::Noeud* Arbre_Lab8::Arbre<E>::_auxPereSym(E*, int, int, E**, int&) [with E = int]’
../BST.inl:28:   instantiated from ‘Arbre_Lab8::Arbre<E>::Arbre(E*, int, int, E**, int&) [with E = int]’

Comment: @Pacane: I just commented out the body of the function (and not the definition) 'void Arbre<E>::_auxPreOrdre(Noeud* noeud, void(* traitement)(E&)) const
' and the code compiles fine on IdeOne and Comeau.

Comment: what happened to the function 'Noeud* Arbre<E>::_auxPereSym(...)' ? Because I tried commenting out 'void ..._auxPreOrdre(...)' but I still get an error from the instantiation of a Node from _auxPereSym (How would you instantiate it, just to make sure?, I tried the 'return new typename Arbre<E>::Noeud(tabS[0]);') And could you explain why I have to specify all those typenames, when I mention it before defining the function? Thanks for you help by the way.